# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Constructed Languages has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Mithical]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who has stepped down as moderator:

[image: Sparksbet]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6271530855038976).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the (literal) votes of confidence, y'all, and I'm looking forward to serving as a moderator here.

And thank you, @Sparksbet, for your service in the time since the site started up.

Qapla'!

Comment: Congratulations and welcome!

Comment: Congrats, and welcome in the moderator's round. I also want to thank the two other candiates for throwing their hats in the ring.